# Cannot run my code for a chatbot application

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, anaconda

Getting this error
my input file is

```
def get_data_from_file(file_path=os.path.('C:/Users/anees/chatbot_data.txt')):
    with open(file_path) as infile:
        cleaned_lines = [line.strip() for line in infile if not line.startswith(('$$$', '###', '==='))]

    return cleaned_lines
```

Error

```
C:\Users\anees\Anaconda3\envs\chatbot\python.exe C:/Users/anees/PycharmProjects/Web_analytics/Assignment1/knowlege_extraction.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/anees/PycharmProjects/Web_analytics/Assignment1/knowlege_extraction.py", line 245, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/anees/PycharmProjects/Web_analytics/Assignment1/knowlege_extraction.py", line 218, in main
    triples = cl.extract_triples(sents)
  File "C:\Users\anees\Anaconda3\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\pyclausie-0.1-py2.7.egg\pyclausie\SubprocessBackend.py", line 62, in extract_triples
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\anees\Anaconda3\envs\chatbot\lib\subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Users\anees\Anaconda3\envs\chatbot\lib\subprocess.py", line 640, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Cant figure the error out please help

Comment: Is the second dot in `os.path.` intentional?

Comment: No it is not intentional ... It is also not necessary to use os.path

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
os.path.join("Users","anees","chatbot_data.txt")
```

to build up the path.

Answer (score 0):

If you are providing full path then the no need to use os.path.join() just use file_path as shown below:

`file_path=r'C:/Users/anees/chatbot_data.txt'`

Or you can use `os.path.join()` as follows:

```
os.path.join("Users","anees","chatbot_data.txt")
```